# Calling a different action in MVC3 using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

My application is in **Asp.net MVC3** coded in **C#.Net**, my requirement is,there is a save to draft button which saves data to a certain table in my database. I have a print button on the view. I'm using SSRS for printing my data. When the user fills the form and click save to draft then that data is saved and then the user can click on Print button to get the SSRS report of the saved data. My issue is when the user click on print button then a new tab should open in which reports should be seen.

Below is my **View Code**

```
    $("#Print_button").live("click", function () {
       $('#My_Form').attr('action', 'My Controller action which passes parameter to 
       SSRS report');
    });
```

HTML of my **Print Button**

```
 <input type="submit" id="Print_button"  value="Print"  />
```

**Controller Code**

```
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Method_That_Pass_ParameterTo_SSRS(MyClass Class_Object)
     {
          My Logic to pass the parameters to SSRS report
          return View(Class_Object);
     }
```

**My attempts to solve the problem**

**1.** I have tried to add Target="_blank" in the button HTML

**2.** window.open('MyAction','_blank') in the Jquery Print_Button click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
As use are trying to get the data to print as a report in a new window/tab.

change your button type to button and define an on click like this.

```
<input type="button" id="Print_button"  value="Print" onclick="ShowReport()"/>
```

then in your action method method.

```
 public ActionResult Method_That_Pass_ParameterTo_SSRS(MyClass Class_Object)
 {
      My Logic to pass the parameters to SSRS report
      return View(Class_Object);
 }
```

Then coming to your script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowReport(e) {
        // you can use dataitem here if needed to pass any variable
        //var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));            
        //BaseUrl will the url of your website
        // for example if url is http://localhost:10259/Home/Index
        //then BaseUrl is "http://localhost:10259/"
        var FullUrl = "Baseurl"+ "ControllerName/ActionName/" + param1(ifany);
        window.open(
                 'FullUrl',
                 '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
                 );
    }        
</script>
```

Just make sure your controller is passing the data properly to the view needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would change logic a bit. If data is already saved by clicking on other button you may not use form to pass parameters.

Instead, you may have `Html.ActionLink` and replace parameters after click. With such approach you may open your result in new tab. Look:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Print", "Action", "Controller", new{param = xxx}, new {@target="_blank", @class="print"})

    <script>
    $(function () {
    $('.print').click(function () {          
                var param = $(".somediv").val() //*Get your param value
                this.href = this.href.replace("xxx", param);
            });
    });
    </script>
```